# ngFor Add Array length - Angular 6

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a response from service as below:

```
dodo: [{
    "did": 1,
    "dname": "Test name",
    "dep": [{
        "cid": 1645,
        "cname": "Table"
     }, {
        "cid": 1651,
        "cname": "Cage"
     }, {
        "cid": 1654,
        "cname": "Accounting"
     }]
     }, {
    "did": 1064,
    "dname": "CB-APIR",
    "dep": [{
        "cid": 1363,
        "cname": "Cage"
     }, {
        "cid": 1364,
        "cname": "Operations"
     }]
}]
```

Now, i have a table structure in which i am looping on `dep` as below:

```
<span *ngFor="let se of element.dodo; let i=index">
    {{ se.dep.length }}
 </span>
```

The above loop displays data as `3 2` in column of total, rather i shall get `5` as column value.

How can i add the values and make it 5?

Comment: can you share the ts code.

Comment: nothing in TS.. this is dataSource for table that has been fed directly from service

Comment: so where is 'element' variable declared ?

Comment: The element is parent node, you may consider it data node

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the sum of deps in your component:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.amountDeps = this.element.dodo.reduce((sum, dod) => sum + dod.dep.length, 0)
}
```

Comment: this i know but i need to do it in HTML as it is based on table rows

Comment: just call a function outside the loop which does the same as Baron wrote {{ count() }}

Comment: a stackblitz would help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stackblitz that implements the solution proposed by Baron and tano.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usejve

Answer (score 0):

In the ts add a function

```
count(){
  return this.element.dodo.reduce((sum, dod) => sum + dod.dep.length, 0)
}
```

and call it in the template in the proper place. It should be called outside the loop

```
    ...
    simply displays a total by dodo:
    <span *ngFor="let se of element.dodo; let i=index">
       {{ se.dep.length }}
    </span>
    displays the accumulated value:
    <span>{{count()}}</span>
    ...
```

Comment: Yes in ts i have done this. But was looking out ways in HTML